# Append elements to Record object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a method that itself defines a default Record<string,string> object, and takes in an argument of type Record<string,string>. The aim is to append the argument Record to the default Record.

```
export interface DataRecord {
  headers: Record<string,string>;
}

public appendToRecord(submittedRecord?: Record<string,string>) {
  let defaultRecord: DataRecord = {
    headers: {
      header1: 'a',
      header2: 'b',
      header3: 'c',
    }
  }
  if(submittedRecord) {
    defaultRecord.headers[submittedRecord.key] = submittedRecord.value;  // not working
  }
}
```

The expectation is that, if submittedRecord contains `header4: 'd'`, I will be able to output defaultRecord.headers and get something like:

```
headers: {
  header1: 'a',
  header2: 'b',
  header3: 'c',
  header4: 'd'
}
```

With my current code, submittedRecord.key and submittedRecord.value is always undefined. I understand that Record may be different from how a typical key-value pair is treated, but I don't know of any other way I can append to an existing Record.

Comment: The key thing to remember here is that `Record<?,?>` instances are *objects*, so you can do standard object manipulations on them, like object property spread (Viktor's answer), `Object.assign`, looping through the result of `Object.values`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
public appendToRecord(submittedRecord?: Record<string,string>) {
  const defaultRecord: DataRecord = {
    headers: {
      header1: 'a',
      header2: 'b',
      header3: 'c',
      ...submittedRecord,
    }
  };
  ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABASwHYLHAZgQwGMwUARfBfAJTEPgBMUBvAKBXZQAsx96cBnAFwoadOPQA8-BHEwBzADQppsjHIB8AbhYBfFi0IAbfP34oAohHwBbKIZKsOKKAFcARobSEU+KFDAY9AAqMKIMABT87tZoCNj0YeIA-MKJkiryShlq6gCUzGxOHPYIKHwELoYIacLklGkoALwFRa1cPHxwQi1tvdy8OACMwgBE+CMKhb2t-Z0ATKNuE1PTTrM4AMyjhMurrQB0h1FuMXFgCbQMK706kzfavXQY-DD2+4YwcuHl+JXVl+Jcg8OHo9AYYM9SiRmhgwAB3CxWWz2cJAlhgfa+fyBEJpcJMdoDOAAFlG9BGKB0aKAA)